# What should I do to make the icon on JButton clearer?

Tags: java, swing

```
submitIcon.setImage(submitIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING));
```

This is my code, and when I try to load the icon on JButton, I notice that the icon becomes very blurry

picture before:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyde.png]

icon on JButton:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTcfl.png]

You can see many sharp places in this icon  ,so I want to know if there is any way to make icon clearer than to change a clearer picture

Comment: Don't bother using setImage() you are better off overriding the buttons paintComponent(Graphics g) and using the graphics object's drawImage() and setRenderingHints() for better performance

Comment: If it is just the "check" you want to see on your button, I would use unicode u2611 and possibly set the font of the button to the desired size.

Comment: got it,thx a lot